# How to fix "Dimension too large" error with lstlisting

Tags: listings

I use `listings` as the `verbatim` enviroment. However, I get the "Dimension too large" error with very long lines. The following is a sample code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[
numbers=left, breaklines, breakautoindent=false, breakindent=0pt
]
Very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long content...
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

The following is the error message.

```
Dimension too large. ...ry very very very very very long content...
Dimension too large. ...ry very very very very very long content...
```

Comment: Not really surprising: your line is far too long! (`listings` will break lines but has first to set them at the natural size.) I find it hard to believe your code really has such poorly-defined line breaks: is this _really_ the case?

Comment: @JosephWright Yes and, in fact, the real case is even longer! The content is not written by some programming language, instead it is the output of my program.

Comment: Perhaps displaying this output with `listings` or a `verbatim` environment is not the right way to do then!

Comment: @JosephWright Some weeks ago I came across a line with 26.825 chars written by pgfplots: https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/97/.  So 2700 isn't sooo long ;-).

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Maybe you are right, but I didn't find better solutions. I will appreciate any advices.

Comment: As a workaround: If you just occasionally have such a long line, you might just interrupt your environment and let the line be broken as normal text, but using the same font as for the environment (e.g., `\texttt{very very ...}`).